# Do the mechanism (SN1 or SN2 ) which reaction follow depends more upon intermediate stability than on substrate and nucleophilic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

For eg : would the reaction of 3-methylbut-2-en-1-ol with HBr follow SN1 mechanism due to stability of your intermediate carbocation stability  or SN2 due to the compound being primary alcohol and good nucleophilic. Also please correct me if I got something wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It will follow SN1 as the intermediate carbocation formed is resonance stabilised.

Comment: So should we consider that the stability of intermediate is key factor in deciding mechanism.

Comment: It's one of the factors. For example : 2° alkyl halide can undergo solvolysis by SN1 ( in aqueous medium) as well as SN2 pathway (with alcohol and amines)